# 7 elements in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have already done some pages with bootstrap, but can't imagine correct way to place 7 equal width elements in a row of 12 spans. And to keep media queries working well.

```
<div class="row">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you give a little bit more information

Comment: To clarify your question, do you want 7 equally spaced elements in the entire row?

Comment: Yes, and we got solution already. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing stopping you from adding your own span7 set of CSS classes. You may want to define them outside of the bootstrap file in case you upgrade to a new version in the future.

If you are using a fixed-0width design, set the width for this new class to 137px.
If you are using a fluid design, set the width to 14.28571428%